# Android: Read APN using ADB shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, apn

According to [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7154/can-i-backup-my-apn-settings), manually-entered APNs are contained here:

```
/data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.x­ml
```

However, this file can't be accessed using `adb shell cat` or `adb pull`.

Is there any workaround for a non-rooted device?

Comment: Is there any Java API to access them or are they considered private to platform private?

Comment: `ll /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/
-rw-rw---- system   system       3108 2014-04-08 18:31 com.android.settings_preferences.xml` only `system` has read/write access on that file.

Comment: we know about this...wt is the solution ?or alternate way to read APN 4.2 and above...

Answer (score 0):

On non-rooted devices is not possible to read system files.

On **rooted** devices with more recent Android version, this worked for me:

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db "select * from carriers;"
```